# WebSphere 8.5: Importing 6.1 Profile ends with "fail to deploy application isclite"

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

On the 6.1 server I run...

> $AdminTask exportWasprofile {-archive c:/tmp/my.car}

On the 8.5 server I see...

> $AdminTask importWasprofile {-archive c:/tmp/my.car}
>   WASX7015E: Exception running command: "$AdminTask importWasprofile {-archive c:/
>   tmp/my.car}"; exception information:
>   com.ibm.wsspi.configarchive.ConfigArchiveException
>   com.ibm.wsspi.configarchive.ConfigArchiveException: fail to deploy application isclite

Is there something special I have to do to properly migrate profiles? Is there a place I can look to get more info as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From [IBM WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/downloads/migtoolkit/config.html)'s website:

> The IBM® WebSphere® Application Server Migration Toolkit is a suite of
>   tools and knowledge collections that enables your organization to
>   quickly and cost-effectively migrate to WebSphere Application Server
>   V7, V8, or V8.5, whether from a previous version of WebSphere
>   Application Server or competitive application servers including Apache
>   Tomcat Server, JBoss Application Server, Oracle Application Server,
>   and Oracle® WebLogic Server.

You should use it as it's bundled in WebSphere Application Server 6.1 (and higher) and offers two scripts that help you in the migration: [WASPreUpgrade](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rmig_WASPreUpgrade.html) and [WASPostUpgrade](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rmig_WASPostUpgrade.html).

**WASPreUpgrade** *"saves the configuration of a previously installed version of WebSphere Application Server into a migration-specific backup directory."* while **WASPostUpgrade** *"retrieves the saved configuration that was created by the WASPreUpgrade command from the backupDirectory that you specified."* (quoting their pages).

Although they might be using wsadmin/Jython, I think you may have more success with these two command-line utilities.

Comment: Thanks, I took the nuclear option on my environment but once I get it back up again I will try this and give it a check if it works. The problem I will have right now is since I destroyed my environment I have the car file but no working 6.1 server. Maybe I can investigate using these commands with a preexisting car.

Comment: You should certainly give the command-line utilities a try as they're exactly for what you're aiming at. Keep us informed.

Comment: In order to upgrade 6.1 server profile you have to use the WASPreUpgrade script from WAS 8.5 of course! And the "currently installed WebSphere Application Server directory name" is d:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61 for example.